# How can I find the 3 highest values in each row and then highlight it?

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the 3 most popular majors for each school. I am given a spreadsheet where every single major is listed corresponding with a percentage of students in each column. I want to find the 3 highest percentages for each row and then highlight it. How can I do this with excel? And if there's a tie, I would want all of them listed if they fall under the 3 highest percentages (like with school3). Thanks in advance!

Example (I would want the three highest percentages in each row):

```
University  Major1   Major2    Major3   Major4 ...
School1     .54      .10       .1       .05
School2     .6       .04       0        .3
School3     .33      .22      .22      .22

University  Major1   Major2    Major3   Major4 ...
School1     **.54      .12       .1**       .05
School2     **.6       .04**       0        **.3**
School3     **.33      .22      .22      .22**
```

Answer (score 4):

For Columns B:E for example. Please select ColumnsB:E, clear any existing Conditional Formatting from that range and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR(B1=LARGE($B1:$E1,1),B1=LARGE($B1:$E1,2),B1=LARGE($B1:$E1,3))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

From Excel 2013:

[image: SO44876552 example]

Comment: Nice. Could be further simplified with `=B1>=Large(.., 3)` I guess :)

Comment: @pnuts, I couldn't find "Format values where this formula is true". I could only find Use a formula to determine which cells to format." I am using Excel 2016 I believe.

Comment: Is that with excel 2016?

Comment: For some reason, it's not working for me :/ Also, in the real spreadsheet, I am  comparing values from G2:AR2, and the values go all the way down to 7502.

Comment: @a-s-h That would work if it's guaranteed that each row has at least three values. If not, the third value isn't there so the boolean condition would return FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

1- Select the first row then Menu:

```
Home --> Conditional Formatting --> Top/Bottom Rules --> Top 10 items -->
then in the textbox on the left of the dialog that appears, type 3
```

2- copy the row <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

3- Select each other row the `PasteSpecial --> Formatting`. do it for each row individually, not the whole range.

Comment: What if there are over 7000 entries?

Comment: If there are over 7000 entries then use a custom formula like in the answer of @pnuts. I wanted to show the easy way for the base line.